# Twitter Bootstrap - Responsive affix

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and I have the following:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="span3">
        <div data-spy="affix">
            <form>
                <!-- inputs and stuff -->
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- span9 and its contents -->

</div>
```

Bootstrap is correctly applying the affix effect on `<div>` and it stays still when I scroll down the page. However, once I resize the page to mobile dimensions and bootstrap responsive effects take place (navbar collapsing/objects aligning nicely under each other), the affixed `<div>` is now on top of other elements of the page and it gets messy. This is happening because `.affix` has `position: fixed` which explains it pretty well.

Now I went to [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html)'s website and resized the page to mobile dimensions, the affixed element (`<ul>` in their case) starts flowing nicely with the page, taking its natural place without going on top of other elements. I have also noticed that once that happens, the class is changed from `affix` to `affix-top`.

I'm not sure if this is their customization or if it's part of the framework, because the framework is apparently not behaving the same way. Can anyone elaborate on this? I need to have the same behavior on my `<div>` where if the page gets resized to mobile dimensions the affixed element takes its natural place.

**Edit:** My observation is a bit flawed. I noticed that the element on their page initially has `affix-top` and once I scroll below `data-top-offset` it changes to `affix`. It still doesn't explain why my `<div>` won't render like their `<ul>` when resized.

Comment: Interesting question, I'm having similar problems myself. In my case, the affixed sidebar gets wider and overlaps the content. I think generally there is a lack of documentation of this new feature.

Comment: @markus-tharkun I think my answer may address your issue as well (`width: auto;`).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Bootstrap uses an [extra CSS file for their docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/docs.css) that overrides the default behavior of some elements.

Specifically, on line 917, they change the `position` of the affixed sidebar (as part of a media query for <767px width) to `static`:

```
.bs-docs-sidenav.affix {
  position: static;
  width: auto;
  top: 0;
}
```

They have several additional custom styles applied to the affixed sidebar; you can view them by using Chrome Web Inspector/Firebug on a phone-sized window.

Comment: I'm wondering why bootstrap doesn't apply the necessary changes, if the affix only works with them. Maybe they're too context dependent.

Comment: I agree, it likely is too context dependent. I was unable to find any discussion on the subject on their [issue tracker](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues).

Comment: @Sara You shouldn't check in the issue tracker since it isn't an issue. It is the intended and documented behavior. "The affix plugin toggles between three classes, each representing a particular state: .affix, .affix-top, and .affix-bottom. You must provide the styles for these classes yourself (independent of this plugin) to handle the actual positions." http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix-usage (However this post was back in 2012 so maybe the documentation has been updated)

Answer (score 28):

**HTML** Don't affix the span3 (or span4 etc) DIV but a child of it; in my case I affixed #sidebar. Also you don't have to add .affix class or data-offset-top="XXX" to this div. The following Javascript will do the trick.

```
  <aside class="span3">
    <div id="sidebar">
     <p>some content</p>
    </div>
  </aside>
```

**CSS** (the below code doesn't exist on bootstrap.css, I copied it from http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/docs.css)

```
.affix-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 400px;
}
```

**Javacript** the following js will change class of #sidebar from .affix to .affix-bottom according to how much page is scrolled

```
   $('#sidebar').affix({
      offset: {
        bottom: 450
      }
   });
```

Indeed on small resolutions #sidebar will overlap other elements. To solve this use bootstrap's media queries http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

As [Sara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1684247/sara) previously pointed out, you can use something like..

```
@media(max-width:767px){
   .affix {
     position: static;
     width: auto;
     top: 0;
    }
}
```

..so that you make the #sidebar behave.

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and my solution was to remove the affix behavior for smaller screen sizes. For example, to remove it for sizes below 1199 pixels:

```
#map {

  @media (min-width: 1199px) {
    &.affix-top {
    }

    &.affix {
      position: fixed;
      top: 20px;
      bottom: 100px;
    }

    &.affix-bottom {
    }
  }
}
```